# Localization of múltiple applications

Tags: c#, architecture, localization

I have several applications for several purposes in my company. Now that we need to translate to Japanese we need to provide a way to store translations.

Provide a central service to every application/team to add and get translations is a good idea?

How can I integrate this in my ASP.NET applications?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of applications? Desktop, web, mobile? WinForms, WPF, MVC, etc? Always connected to an in-house network or capable of independent operation?

Comment: Web applications and always connected to an in house network

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I did this for a combination of web (MVC and WCF) and desktop (WinForms and WPF) apps.

A database repository of common strings was built that contained common words and phrases like Cancel, Save, etc. as well as business specific terms. Along with the DB a dev team utility app that would build a base localization library project. Individual app teams could then inherit this base and expand upon it for their specific needs. The idea was to provide the base while allowing customization to avoid delaying a project that needed new phrases added.

Within the individual apps, the strings were replaced by calls to the library. For example,
CancelButtton.Text = LibName.GetPhrase("Cancel"). The current CultureInfo was used to determine the user's language but this could be overriden for testing. If the phrase wasn't in the DB, it would default to the supplied string.

We had some debate over using local files, such as RESX, vs. a database repository. The plan ended up being to start with a database first and add the capability local files if there was a performance issue or the need for unconnected operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use localized strings in something like an XML structure and just extract the information from the XML file. Every language got it's own XML file.

For example (from Android Localization):

@string/info_string = "Information in English"

Another file

@string/info_string = "Informationen in deutscher Sprache"

In your program you simply get the information that `info_string` stores.